# How to properly parse this XML with C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML code:

```
<Presets>
  <Preset ID="0" Name="aaaa">
    <IncludedChampions>
      <ID>5</ID>
      <ID>6</ID>
      <ID>7</ID>
    </IncludedChampions>
  </Preset>
  <Preset ID="1" Name="some">
    <IncludedChampions>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <ID>5</ID>
      <ID>6</ID>
    </IncludedChampions>
   </Preset>
</Presets>
```

and I'm trying to parse it with this:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("./config.xml");
while (reader.Read())
{
   while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Preset"))
   {
       presetList.Add(new Preset());
       presetList[presetList.Count - 1].name = reader.GetAttribute(1);
       Console.WriteLine("Preset list ID " + Convert.ToString(presetList.Count - 1));

      while (reader.ReadToFollowing("ID"))
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Champion ID " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
      }
   }
}
```

But in the output, I only see 'Preset list ID 0' and then all the ID's. Where did the other Preset ID go? Thanks!

Comment: Are you bound to `XmlReader`?  Is `XElement` an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`XmlReader.ReadToFollowing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162536.aspx) is documented as follows:

> Reads until an element with the specified qualified name is found.

Now, from ID 7 in the first Preset, what's the "next following element" with the name "ID"? It's ID 4, of course... it doesn't only search *siblings*.

As Nick suggests, using LINQ to XML would make this a lot simpler... or even just the `XmlDocument` model, if you're really stuck on .NET 2.

Here's the relevant LINQ to XML code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("config.xml");
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("Preset"))
{
    var preset = new Preset { name = element.Attribute("Name").Value };
    presetList.Add(preset);
    Console.WriteLine("Preset list ID " + preset);
    foreach (var id in element.Descendants("ID"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought XmlWriter/Reader was the way to go. I'll try using XDocument from now on then! Thanks!

Comment: @argoneus: `XmlReader` is good if you really want to stream documents - if they're huge, basically. If you're happy to load the whole thing into memory, LINQ to XML is *wonderful*.

Comment: one last thing, is it better to use XmlWriter or LINQ to XML?

Comment: @argoneus: Again, unless you *need* to use `XmlWriter` due to writing a huge file in a streaming fashion, I'd use LINQ to XML every time.

Comment: I don't quite see how to put code inside my xdoc.. e.g. new XElement("Presets", 
     foreach (var item in presetList) {}

gives me errors

Comment: @argoneus: You should read a full LINQ to XML tutorial. It's not worth trying to do this in comments.